# override protected block method and remove field from prepareForm

Tags: magento2.3

How can i override the block's protected method and remove fields from form

```
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Edit\Form;
```

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use NameSpace\ModuleName\Helper\Data;
use NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Order;
use NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Quote;

class Info extends Template
{

```
protected $quote;


protected $order;

protected $helperData;

protected $formFactory;

protected $form;

protected $orderRepository;

protected $orderStatusConfig;

protected $orderStateConfig;


public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    Data $helperData,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status $orderStatusConfig,
    \ModuleName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Order\State $orderStateConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->helperData        = $helperData;
    $this->formFactory       = $formFactory;
    $this->orderRepository   = $orderRepository;
    $this->orderStatusConfig = $orderStatusConfig;
    $this->orderStateConfig  = $orderStateConfig;
}


public function getForm()
{
    if ($this->form === null) {
        $this->form = $this->formFactory->create();
        $this->prepareForm();
    }

    return $this->form;
}


public function getQuote()
{
    return $this->helperData->getQuote();
}


public function setQuote($quote)
{
    $this->quote = $quote;

    return $this;
}


public function getOrder()
{
    $order = $this->helperData->getOrder();
    if (!$order) {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order   = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    }

    return $order;
}


public function setOrder($order)
{
    $this->order = $order;

    return $this;
}

protected function prepareForm()
{
    $fieldset = $this->form->addFieldset('main', []);



    $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
    $timeFormat = $this->_localeDate->getTimeFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM);
    $fieldset->addType(
        'custom_date',
        \MageWorx\OrderEditor\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Element\CustomDate::class
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'created_at',
        'custom_date',
        [
            'input_format' => \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'name'         => 'created_at',
            'label'        => __('Order Date'),
            'title'        => __('Order Date'),
            'required'     => true,
            'date_format'  => $dateFormat,
            'time_format'  => $timeFormat
        ]
    );

    $statusOptions = $this->orderStatusConfig->toOptionArray();
    array_shift($statusOptions);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'status',
        'select',
        [
            'name'     => 'status',
            'label'    => __('Status'),
            'title'    => __('Status'),
            'values'   => $statusOptions,
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'state',
        'select',
        [
            'name'     => 'state',
            'label'    => __('State'),
            'title'    => __('State'),
            'values'   => $this->orderStateConfig->toOptionArray(),
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );

    $this->form->addFieldNameSuffix('order[info]');
    $this->form->setValues($this->getFormValues());

    return $this;
}

public function getFormValues()
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();

    return [
        'increment_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
        'created_at'   => $order->getCreatedAt(),
        'status'       => $order->getStatus(),
        'state'        => $order->getState(),
    ];
}


public function getSubmitButtonHtml()
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class)
                 ->setData(
                     [
                         'id'    => 'info-submit',
                         'label' => __('Submit'),
                         'type'  => 'button',
                         'class' => 'edit primary',
                         'style' => 'margin-top: 1em; float:right;',
                     ]
                 )
                 ->toHtml();

    return $html;
}


public function getCancelButtonHtml()
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class)
                 ->setData(
                     [
                         'label' => __('Cancel'),
                         'id'    => 'info-cancel',
                         'class' => 'edit primary',
                         'type'  => 'button',
                         'style' => 'margin-top: 1em; float:left;',
                     ]
                 )
                 ->toHtml();

    return $html;
}


public function getNotice()
{
    return __(
        'Note that changing the order\'s details won\'t recalculate the taxes and discounts.
        You should adjust the prices manually if necessary.'
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share which module are you trying to override?, your code is not clear enough

Comment: In this "protected function prepareForm()"  i want to remove state field, this block function

Comment: @RomerRios update the code i ' $fieldset->addField(
            'state',
            'select',
            [
                'name'     => 'state',
                'label'    => __('State'),
                'title'    => __('State'),
                'values'   => $this->orderStateConfig->toOptionArray(),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );'